# Progress bar that update after completion of each function in Django

Tags: python, django, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

I make an OCR application which take an input image from user and do this following steps (In order):

1. Image Processing
2. Bounding Box
3. Character Segmentation
4. Predicting each characters

But Since this all above steps is taking too much time, so I decided to implement a progress bar which show how much process is done to users. But I am new to Django and I read about [celery-progress-bar](https://buildwithdjango.com/blog/post/celery-progress-bars/). Ans I can't figure out how do I use this in my app.

Here is what I thought, what my view.py should look like:

```
def my_function(request): 
    # Here I want to start progress bar
    ....
    cleared_image = image_processing(image) # Image Processing
    segmented = character_segmentation(cleared_image) # Segmented Characters as list (in sorted)
    .....
    predicted = [] # This list will store prediction of each character
    for character in segmented:
         ....
         prediction = predict(obj.picture)
         predicted.append(prediction)
         ### Here I want to Update Progress bar
         ....

def image_processing(image):
    # Correct skew and Do Image Processing
    ### Here I want to Update Progress bar 
    return resulted_image

def character_segmentation(image):
    #Do Bounding Box and character Segmentation
    ### Here I want to Update Progress bar
    return list_of_characters
```

Comment: A short Info for you. U can solve it in another way. You can search for "loading symbols" and put them to your frontend. There you can use js. When u click on the button that starts the heavy progress u can make the loading symbol visible. so when ur tasks are finished, the site is refreshing and the loading symbol is away too! just a small hint from another beginner x)

Comment: You mean "loading spinner". Yeah I can do that too, Thank you for your information. But the thing is I am a beginner, and I want to learn new things and plus this is my learning project, so I wanna try this as loading bar

Comment: Yeah it was just a short info. i also bookmarked the question bc i want to see the solutions:D hope someone can help you